# Why the last function is not executing?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping Dmoz website and I scraped the about page but when I made another function by the name `parse_editor` and tried to scrape, it is not giving me the result.

```
from ..items import DmoztutorialItem
import scrapy


class DmozSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Dmoz'
    start_urls = ['http://dmoz-odp.org/']
    about_page = 'http://dmoz-odp.org/docs/en/about.html'
    editor = 'http://dmoz-odp.org/docs/en/help/become.html'

    def parse(self, response):
        # collect data on first page
        items = {
            'Navbar': response.css('#main-nav a::text').extract(),
            'Category_names': response.css('.top-cat a::text').extract(),
            'Subcategories': response.css('.sub-cat a::text').extract(),
            'About_page': self.about_page,
            'Become_an_editor': self.editor
        }

        # save and call request to another page
        yield response.follow(self.about_page, self.parse_about, self.editor, self.parse_editor, meta={'items': items})

    def parse_about(self, response):
        # do your stuff on second page
        items = response.meta['items'] 
        items['Headings'] = response.css('h2::text , #mainContent h1::text').extract()  # add your logics
        items['Paragraphs'] = response.css('p::text').extract()
        items['3 Projects'] = response.css('li~ li+ li b a::text , li:nth-child(1) b a::text').extract()
        items['About Dmoz'] = response.css('.nav ul a::text , li:nth-child(2) b a::text').extract()
        items['Languages'] = response.css('.nav~ .nav a::text').extract()
        items['You can make a difference'] = response.css('dd::text , #about-contribute::text').extract()
        items['Further information'] = response.css('li::text , #about-more-info a::text').extract()
        yield items

    def parse_editor(self, response):
        # do your stuff on third page
        editor_items = response.meta['items']
        editor_items['Heading'] = response.css('#mainContent h1::text').extract()
        yield editor_items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write everything in one `response.follow`, that is wrong. It takes one pair url-callback. So write them in two separate functions:

Incorrect variant:

```
yield response.follow(self.about_page, self.parse_about, self.editor, self.parse_editor, meta={'items': items})
```

Correct variant:

```
yield response.follow(self.about_page, self.parse_about, meta={'items': items})
yield response.follow(self.editor, self.parse_editor, meta={'items': items})
```

You can write first `follow` in `parse` function; call `parse_about` and there make second `follow` and yield final item in `parse_editor` function.

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem. I have another question. Whenever I print this, it appears randomly in the command prompt. Is there any way of showing these contents in a proper manner so that I could understand, which page has which content? I mean I want to divide it in command prompt so that I could read it easily.

Comment: Since `scrapy` makes requests in async way, probably it is better for you add some debug information manually, for example, with `print` or `logging` lib. Btw, will appreciate if you will mark this answer as accepted.